# Generating sum of nested NumPy arrays in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have array like this :

```
[array([1,2,3,4]),array([5,6,7,8]),array([1,0,5,6]),array([8,1,2,9])]
```

I want `sum_Array=[10,26,12,20]`

can somebody help?
how to do??

Comment: Though this is fairly straightforward, I'd rather not answer until I know what you've tried and why it didn't work. Could you post some of your own code please?

Answer (score 1):

If your initial array is `np.array()` you can use `sum`:

```
arr = np.array([array([1,2,3,4]),array([5,6,7,8]),array([1,0,5,6]),array([8,1,2,9])])
sum_array = np.sum(arr, axis=1)
#[10 26 12 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a list of numpy arrays, you could just use list comprehension with `np.sum()` like this:

`arr = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([5,6,7,8]),np.array([1,0,5,6]),np.array([8,1,2,9])]
sum_array = [np.sum(a) for a in arr]`

This will give `[10, 26, 12, 20]`.